# Angular - Override/Mock methods get, post, put, delete from HTTP for testing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to mock the `Http` class so I could inject it on a service that I want to test.

Usually, I create a mock class that extends the class that will be override. For this case, I did something like this:

```
export class MockHttp extends Http {
    constructor(){super(undefined, undefined);}
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            observer.next(undefined);
            observer.complete();
        });
    }
}
```

But the `intelisense` of `vs code` give me the following error, on the method `get`:

> Property 'get' in type 'MockAppHttpClientService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Http'.

Any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write your own mock as it is not that trivial task. Angluar already provides utilities to mock http client for unit testing. It is described in sufficient details in official documentation

https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services

In short, use `HttpClientTestingModule`